# Spring OAuth2 SSO + Keycloak with Desktop Application

Tags: excel, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak, excel-addins

I have a Spring framework + Spring security application and using spring-security-oauth2-client for OIDC authentication with Keycloak. On web browser, SSO works great.

I have a Excel Add-in for users to upload data on to the web platform. How can I enable SSO authentication for Excel-Addin(C#, desktop application)